# Deploying Express server&React client to Heroku fails; no error in the logs, just 404

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I'm writing a simple client/server app and getting into an issue when deploying to Heroku. My code is [here](https://github.com/nowiesz/go) (currently at commit 11351f8e15a872e50595ad305eb4a935bba3a0d6) and I based it on [this](https://github.com/nowiesz/go) and [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-an-express-server-on-heroku-32244fe5a250/) tutorial (both suggest the same directoy structure, just differ in the main package.json scripts).

At first, I got an error `cannot access '/app/build/static/js/*.js'`, which I resolved by running this command (which neither of the tutorials mentioned :-/).

```
heroku config:set JS_RUNTIME_TARGET_BUNDLE=/app/client/build/js/*.js
```

I thought I was good, but no. Despite Heroku no longer complains, there is simply nothing out there, just 404. I bet it's something trivial, but I'm honestly running out of ideas. Please help.

```
2020-05-05T15:11:49.896205+00:00 app[api]: Set JS_RUNTIME_TARGET_BUNDLE config vars by user [...]
2020-05-05T15:11:49.896205+00:00 app[api]: Release v19 created by user [...]
2020-05-05T15:11:51.492041+00:00 app[web.1]: Going down, terminating child processes...
2020-05-05T15:12:00.850825+00:00 app[web.1]: Injecting runtime env into /app/client/build/static/js/2.e0399e74.chunk.js (from .profile.d/inject_react_app_env.sh)
2020-05-05T15:12:00.949574+00:00 app[web.1]: Injecting runtime env into /app/client/build/static/js/main.e25999d1.chunk.js (from .profile.d/inject_react_app_env.sh)
2020-05-05T15:12:01.041037+00:00 app[web.1]: Injecting runtime env into /app/client/build/static/js/runtime-main.b186b88b.js (from .profile.d/inject_react_app_env.sh)
2020-05-05T15:12:01.368403+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting log redirection...
2020-05-05T15:12:01.368798+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting nginx...
2020-05-05T15:12:01.632649+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-05T15:12:16.518752+00:00 heroku[run.5999]: State changed from up to complete
2020-05-05T15:12:32.064267+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bn-go.herokuapp.com request_id=8e4f6060-26e2-4283-8637-c79f09e61778 fwd="106.72.42.32" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=403 protocol=https
2020-05-05T15:29:07.968532+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/load" host=bn-go.herokuapp.com request_id=b1942d65-eac0-4873-ba4b-b07a41efe2b1 fwd="106.72.42.32" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=403 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I figured it out. It was create-react-app-buildpack, which changed dyno setting from "npm start" to "bin/boot". I removed it and it all works fine.